# Groupby Pandas and compare multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

A duplicate occurs if each unique entry in 'value_pack' has the same 'value' and 'discount' as another value_pack

```
Value_pack  value   discount
   Val 1    ADA        0
   Val 1    ADB       100
   Val 2    ADA        0
   Val 2    ADB       100
   Val 3    ADA       50
   Val 3    ADB       40
   Val 4    ADA       40
```

I want to groupby each unique entry in 'value_pack' and compare it to every other entry.
For example, Va1 1 and Val 2 are the same.

df.groupby(['Value_pack]) but I am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Output would be Val 1, Val 2

Comment: Yes value pack that is duplicated should be returned.

Comment: if you have val1 has 3 entries and val 2 has 2 entries and the first 2 entries of val 1 equal the 2 entries of val 2, do you consider this as a duplicate value pack?

Comment: No, that is not a duplicate. It has to contain the same amount of entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can first make a temporary DataFrame `z` where each row is a value pack, and each column is a tuple of all values:

```
z = (df
    .sort_values(['value', 'discount'])
    .groupby('Value_pack', as_index=False)
    .agg(tuple))
```

So, in our example `z` is:

```
  Value_pack       value  discount
0      Val 1  (ADA, ADB)  (0, 100)
1      Val 2  (ADA, ADB)  (0, 100)
2      Val 3  (ADA, ADB)  (50, 40)
3      Val 4      (ADA,)     (40,)
```

Then merge `z` to itself on `['value', 'discount']`, and take records where `Value_pack_x < Value_pack_y` (since it's symmetric, and you don't want to have `Val1 - Val2` and `Val2 - Val1`):

```
(z
    .merge(z, on=['value', 'discount'])
    .drop(columns=['value', 'discount'])
    .query('Value_pack_x < Value_pack_y'))
```

Output:

```
  Value_pack_x Value_pack_y
1        Val 1        Val 2
```